# moving array elements inside the array

Tags: arrays, julia

Whats an efficient way to move elements to a new index inside an array like this?

```
A = collect(1:9)  # [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

# now lets move elements 1:3 to index 2 
move!(A,1:3,2)    # [4,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9]

# lets move the 9 to index 3 now
move!(A,9:9,3)    # [4,1,9,2,3,5,6,7,8]

# or this
move!(A,3:6,5)    # [4,1,6,7,9,2,3,5,8]
```

I always end up resizing the array or swapping like mad. Is there an efficient (=fast) way to solve this?

Comment: The closest you can get, as far as I know, is `permute!`. E.g. `permute!(A, [4;1:3;5:endof(A)])`

Comment: I'll take a look into this, thanks for the hint and example. I will let you know if it solves the problem.

Comment: @DNF thanks! I now had the time to take a look at the docs for permute! and realised, I totally misread it the first time. Thanks, that should work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving a range of elements in an array to a new location can be viewed as rotating a larger range which includes the moved elements on one edge and the destination location. The rotation is by just enough to bring the moved elements to position and push the others away.

Since the length of the vector remains unchanged, it would be best to do this operation in-place without allocations. Doing this rotation in-place is a little tricky, but doable as the code below demonstrates:

```
function rotate!(v,n::Int)
  l = length(v)
  l>1 || return v
  n = n % l
  n = n < 0 ? n+l : n
  n==0 && return v
  for i=1:gcd(n,l)
    tmp = v[i]
    dst = i
    src = dst+n
    while src != i
      v[dst] = v[src]
      dst = src
      src += n
      if src > l
        src -= l
      end
    end
    v[dst] = tmp
  end
  return v
end

move!(A,rng,loc) = begin 
  rotate!(view(A,min(first(rng),loc):max(last(rng),length(rng)+loc-1)),first(rng)-loc)
  return A
end

A = collect(1:9)
@show move!(A,1:3,2) == [4,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9]
@show move!(A,9:9,3) == [4,1,9,2,3,5,6,7,8]
@show move!(A,3:6,5) == [4,1,6,7,9,2,3,5,8]
```

The last lines of code replicate the example in the question. Essentially, only the `view` allocates memory and the `rotate!` function is totally in-place.

Comment: PS edge cases are tricky in these routines, so any corrections will be welcome

Comment: perfect solution for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For single values you could do something like this?

```
function flipvals!(A, ind1, ind2)
     flip = view.(A, [ind1,ind2])
     flip .= reverse(flip)
     return nothing
end
```

Otherwise `permute!`as @DNF suggested is a good idea.

Update: As comment by OP suggested this could be achieved more easily by:

```
A[ind1], A[ind2] = A[ind2], A[ind1]
```

Comment: I cant test this right now but doesnt this do the same thing like A[ind1], A[ind2] = A[ind2], A[ind1]?

Comment: That should be the same thing, and slightly cheaper